# error while calling webdriver method in Jmeter

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

I have created JAR for a Junit class and placed it in Jmeter lib\Junit folder and placed selenium JARs in Jmeter>lib the method is getting deselected while running it and then getting below error
getting error while running it from Jmeter.
Failed to create an instance of the class:null, reasons may be missing both empty constructor and one String constructor or failure to instantiate constructor, check warning messages in jmeter log file

Comment: Provide more info plz with log